# Touch ID での認証後、Modal で UITabBarController に画面遷移を行う方法

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

まず、アプリの起動時に First View を表示し、First View の viewDidLoad 関数で Touch ID の認証を行う記述をしました。

[image: StoryBoard]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let context = LAContext()
    var error :NSError?
    let localizedReason = "Touch ID で保護"

    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error){

        //Tocuh ID に対応
        context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: localizedReason, reply: {
            success, error in

            if success {

                let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

                let next:UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home")
                    as UIViewController

                next.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal

                self.presentViewController(next, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else {
                switch error!.code {
                case LAError.AuthenticationFailed.rawValue:
                    NSLog("認証失敗")
                case LAError.UserCancel.rawValue:
                    NSLog("キャンセル")
                case LAError.UserFallback.rawValue:
                    NSLog("パスコードを入力を選択")
                case LAError.PasscodeNotSet.rawValue:
                    NSLog("パスコードが設定されていない")
                case LAError.SystemCancel.rawValue:
                    NSLog("システムによってキャンセルされた")
                default:
                    NSLog("不明なエラー")
                    return
                }
            }
        })

    } else {
        //Tocuh ID に非対応
        NSLog("Touch IDに対応してない")
    }

}
```

Touch ID での認証に成功した後、Modal の FlipHorizontal で画面遷移を行いたいのですが、
スクリーンショットのようになってしまい、TabBarItem の icon が表示されません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

一度、その TabBarItem をタップするか、しばらく時間が経つ(その時間は起動するたびにまちまち)と表示されるようになりますが、
通常の画面遷移の時のように一発で表示されるようにしたいです。

遷移先は Main.Storyboard にある UITabBarController、Storyboard ID は "Home" です。

どのようにすればよいか、ご教授願います。

なお、Apple Swift version 2.1 (swiftlang-700.1.101.6 clang-700.1.76) を使用しています。

Comment: 画面遷移後のスクリーンショットが貼られていないようですが？

Comment: XcodeのバージョンとSwiftのバージョンを追記してください。Xcode 7 + Swift 2.0では、`let next:UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home")
                    as UIViewController`の`as UIViewController`は不用です。

Comment: @Harawo さん
コメントありがとうございます。スクリーンショット、Swift のバージョンの記述を追加しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

症状の再現を確認しました。ボタンのアクションメソッドで、`TabBar Controller`に遷移するときは問題ないのに、クロージャ内で遷移すると、（未表示の）タブのアイコンが、欠けますね。
はっきりした理由はわかりませんが、私は、クロージャ内で`UITabBarController`を生成し、遷移することに原因があると仮定し、それに沿って、プログラムを修正したところ、アイコンが欠けなくなりました。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // インスタンス変数として、TabBar Controllerを宣言
    var theTabBarController: UITabBarController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        theTabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home")
                        as! UITabBarController
        theTabBarController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal
        // この時点でTabBarControllerインスタンスはできあがっている。

        let context = LAContext()
        var error :NSError?
        let localizedReason = "Touch ID で保護"

        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error){

            //Tocuh ID に対応
            context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: localizedReason, reply: {
                success, error in

                if success {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        // 認証成功したら、モーダル表示。
                        self.presentViewController(self.theTabBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    })
                } else {
                    switch error!.code {
                    case LAError.AuthenticationFailed.rawValue:
                        print("認証失敗") // NSLogじゃなく、print()を使おう。
                    case LAError.UserCancel.rawValue:
                        print("キャンセル")
                    case LAError.UserFallback.rawValue:
                        print("パスコードを入力を選択")
                    case LAError.PasscodeNotSet.rawValue:
                        print("パスコードが設定されていない")
                    case LAError.SystemCancel.rawValue:
                        print("システムによってキャンセルされた")
                    default:
                        print("不明なエラー")
                        return
                    }
                }
            })

        } else {
            //Tocuh ID に非対応
            print("Touch IDに対応してない。エラーコード：\(error!.code)") // どうせならエラーコードも出力しておく。
        }

    }
}
```

いいたいことは、`TabBar Controller`をクロージャの外で生成するということです。

関係ないところで、気になった点に修正を加えていますので、余裕ができたときにご覧ください。

Comment: 理由は`evaluatePolicy(_:, localizedReason:, reply:)`のコールバックはメインスレッド以外で呼ばれるからですね。ちょっと描画が欠けたりするのはたいていはメインスレッド以外でUIを作成・更新したことによって起こります。なので、`presentViewController(_:, animated:completion:)`を呼び出す部分も、たまたま問題なく描画されてるだけなので、厳密にはメインスレッドにディスパッチする必要があります。

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi プログラムコードの修正、ありがとうございました。スレッドを使うプログラムは、危険という先入観があって、なかなか手を付けられなかったのですが、まじめに勉強しなくてはと、実感いたしました。

Comment: Harawo さん
kishikawakatsumi さん

回答ありがとうございます。
お二方が書いてくださったコード、当方でも期待通りに動作することを確認できました。
なぜこのような現象になってしまうかということについて、理由も説明してくださり、こちらも理解することが出来ました。